# Reshaping array of shape x into an array of shape (x,y)

Tags: python, numpy

I am following a tutorial to implement the K-nearest Neighbor algorithm on a dataset.

I have an array of shape (6003,) and I want to do this:

```
data = data.reshape((data.shape[0], 3072))
```

However, I am getting this error:

> cannot reshape array of size 6003 into shape (6003,3072)

Any help on this, please? Thanks!

Comment: `reshape` only changes the shape, not the total number of elements!  It is not `resize`.

Comment: you can't reshape `(6003,)` to `(6003,3072)`,reshaping into 2d array doesn't mean that dimensions will increase,it should be a multiple of `6003`

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like `np.repeat`?

Comment: The data must have had a shape such as [6003, 48, 64] (say if it was a grayscale image). From here the purpose of reshape is to reduce the dimension to be suitable for an algorithm like KNN. Can you check if the data has the correct shape before this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you reshape a numpy array the total number elements shouldn't change.
e.g. `a =[2,3,4,5,1,7]` if you want to reshape this to a `2D`array then the dimensions multiplied should be equal to the total number elements in the original array a. 
this means you can reshape array a in to dimension of  `(1,6) (2,3),(6,1),(3,2)`.

the title of your question does give away the error by the way.

> Reshaping array of shape `(x,)` into an array of shape `(x,y)`

is impossible because you are trying to add  more elements into your original data. 
an array of shape `(x,)` can only be reshaped into an array of shape `(x/y,y)`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reshape into an incompatible shape. Now, what do I mean by that? Look at this example:

```py
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], 
              [4, 5, 6], 
             ])
```

The shape of this array is:

```py
a.shape
```

```py
>> (2, 3)
```

Array `a` has `2 x 3 = 6` elements. Let's try to reshape it into a `(2, 6)` array

```py
a.reshape(2, 6)
```

This raises

```
>> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 6 into shape (2,6)
```

Notice that we were trying to make an array that has `2 x 3 = 6` elements into an array that would have `2 x 6 = 12` elements. But NumPy cannot add those extra elements into your original array and give that your desired shape. So it raises `ValueError`.

In your case, you are trying to make an array with `6003` elements into an array that will have `6003 x 3072 = 18441216` elements!