# Why does my list shape change in a concurrent futures loop?

Tags: python, list, numpy, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

Can someone tell me why the second time I loop around I can format my numpy list? This is the error I get.

```
(venv) C:\Users\ENG-DESKTOP-4\PycharmProjects\Delay Tracker>python -m flight_weather_1
```

```
Shape of list is : (500, 1, 10) 
shape of unformatted numpy is (500, 1, 10)
shape of formatted numpy is (500, 10)
Shape of list is : (500,)
shape of unformatted numpy is (500,)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
> return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
> File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)
> File "C:\Users\ENG-DESKTOP-4\PycharmProjects\Delay Tracker\flight_weather_1.py", line 121, in 
> results_formatted = results_thou.reshape(500, 10)
>
> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 500 into shape (500,10)

```
def index_weather(index):
    Iata_ = (first_mil.iloc[index]['ORIGIN'])
    flight_time_ = (first_mil.iloc[index]['FL_DATE'])
    weather_data = weather_from_IATA(Iata_, flight_time_)
    return weather_data


for i in range(2):
    index_ = list(range(1 + (i * 500), (500 + 1) + (i * 500)))

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        secs = index_
        results = executor.map(index_weather, secs)
        results_list = list(results)
        print("Shape of list is : " + str(np.shape(results_list)))
        results_thou = np.array(results_list)

        results_list.clear()

        print("shape of unformatted numpy is", np.shape(results_thou))
        results_formatted = results_thou.reshape(500, 10)
        print("shape of formatted numpy is", np.shape(results_formatted))
        results_pd = pd.DataFrame(results_formatted)
        pd.concat((all2, results_pd), axis=0)
```

Comment: Did you try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code? For example, does the problem still occur without multithreading? At what points do you expect the code to be synchronized?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may already be answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428074/reshaping-array-of-shape-x-into-an-array-of-shape-x-y)

From Kellem Negasi's answer:

"when you reshape a numpy array the total number elements shouldn't change. e.g. a =[2,3,4,5,1,7] if you want to reshape this to a 2Darray then the dimensions multiplied should be equal to the total number elements in the original array a."

From your output what I can guess you have tried to assign the unformatted numpy
From your error output:

```
  ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 500 into shape (500,10),
```

leading all the way back to your index_ variable which has a length of 500 elements
Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Even without the `concurrent` stuff:

```
In [32]: for i in range(2):
    ...:     index_ = list(range(1 + (i * 500), (500 + 1) + (i * 500)))
    ...: 
    ...:     results = index_.copy()
    ...:     results_list = list(results)
    ...:     print("Shape of list is : " + str(np.shape(results_list)))
    ...:     results_thou = np.array(results_list)
    ...:     print("shape of unformatted numpy is", np.shape(results_thou))
    ...:     results_formatted = results_thou.reshape(500, 10)
    ...:     print("shape of formatted numpy is", np.shape(results_formatted))
    ...: 
Shape of list is : (500,)
shape of unformatted numpy is (500,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [32] in <cell line: 1>
    results_formatted = results_thou.reshape(500, 10)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 500 into shape (500,10)
```

For `i=0`

```
In [36]: np.shape(index_)
Out[36]: (500,)

In [41]: i=0; range(1 + (i * 500), (500 + 1) + (i * 500))
Out[41]: range(1, 501)
```

I assumed

```
results = executor.map(index_weather, secs)
```

produce a result that matches `secs` shape.  But your (500, 1, 10) first result suggests that for that case `index_weather` returned (1,10) arrays.  Figuring out when that's the case, and when it just returns a scalar, isn't something I can do.